# Did I miss something?

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

I'm helping a friend process a visa to the UK using the Warsaw TLS centre.

On the TLSwebsite I just noticed a "Pending" section that had a confirm button for the address and some forms. Would this help the process without clicking confirm? It's now been 15 days since the interview.

Any advice would be amazing, it's hell waiting for this process.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand the question correctly. You checked the TLS centre by chance after 15 days and noted that you need to confirm some details?

1. Yes, confirm as quickly as possible (after checking that the details are indeed correct).
2. Your friend probably received an E-Mail asking for confirmation but failed to notice it! Probably you inadvertently delayed the process.
3. General advice:  When you provide contact details like E-Mail or telephone in a application make sure you can indeed be contacted. Check your mailbox and your voicebox.